# screen.nodelay(True) fills up terminal with diagonal lines of -1 and blocks input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Im using a raspberry pi and trying to make it so that when a press a key an LED turns on, and off when I let go of that key. Pressing the key (in this case "a") does nothing, but oddly enough pressing "q" stops the program

Here is my code

```
import curses
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
screen.nodelay(True)
screen.keypad(True)

screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:

        char = screen.getch()
        print char
        if char == ord('q'):
            break
        elif char == ord('a'):
            GPIO.output(12,True)

        else:
            GPIO.output(12,False)

finally:
    curses.nocbreak();screen.keypad(0);curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What is the problem? The blocked input from title or the behavior when typing "a"? If "q" works this contradicts a blocked input.

Comment: I don't know if blocked input is the correct terminology, but the problem is that when I press "a" the LED does not turn on.

Comment: Have you tried it with a simple loop for blinking, roughly `while True: GPIO.output(12,True);time.sleep(1);GPIO.output(12,False);time.sleep(1)`?

Comment: Yes I have and it does fix the problem of the LED not turning on, but now the LED has a big "gap" in turning on after the first fraction of a second. So the pattern upon pressing "a" is: on for about 1/10th of a second, off for about 1/2rd of a second, then constantly on until "a" is let go. After playing around with the values for time.sleep() a bit I've found that the best ones are: ```GPIO.output(12, True) has to be 0.03. every other value seems to give me one problem or another. GPIO.output (12, False) can be pretty much anything, but values <=0.1 work best``` but can't get rid of the gap